# iCloud: Untrust a saved Web browser

Tags: icloud

I recently accessed [iCloud Website](http://icloud.com) using a device that I don't personally own and generally use.

After successfully logging-in by entering my Apple ID/Password and the Two Factor Authentication code, I was asked if I would like to **trust the browser**, so as to skip entering Two Factor Authentication code every time I login, I complied. (It isn't a public device and there is no possibility of unauthorized access)

[image]

This gave me the of flexibility to easily login in with just my Apple ID and password when I don't have any of my trusted Apple device around to get the Two Factor Authentication code.

Now, I am done using the device and will be returning it to the original owner. How do I **untrust the Web browser**?, i.e. require it to ask for Two Factor Authentication code next time a login is performed using my Apple ID? Also, is there a way to see a list of all similar trusted browsers and untrust them?

Comment: you logged in with your account ? just remove that device from your profile, so next time your credentials are used to log in it will ask again.

Comment: How do I remove the device? I didn't log into a device. I signed into iCloud website via Chrome browser running on an Android device.

Comment: Not sure what are you trying to accomplish here. Using some else device you logged in with your credentials. Now you want to give that device back but that person still can use your credentials to log in ? Is that correct ?

Comment: I am not sharing the credentials. I have already logged out from the browser. I want to ensure that someone with access to my login credentials couldn’t log into iCloud using that device without needing to enter Two-Factor Authentication code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that a cookie (probably X-APPLE-WEBAUTH-HSA-TRUST) is stored when you choose to trust the browser. Clearing cookies should essentially disable this functionality and require a 2FA code to log in again.

When you sign out of iCloud using the browser (Click your name in the top right corner and `Sign Out`), you are also presented with this dialog:

[image: A screen shot of an iCloud Sign Out dialog asking the user if they want to be remembered in this browser]

If you uncheck `Remember me on this browser so I don't have to verify my identity next time.` and sign out successfully, the browser will require a 2FA code the next time you log in.

Answer (score 1):

1- First sign out

[image]

2- next time yo will be asked again to trust the browser

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you no longer has the device, you may choose to sign out of all browsers. Go to the iCloud website, sign in, and then Account Settings. At the bottom of the page, you should see the option below.

[image]